# SharePoint 2010 Document Library version history

Tags: document-library, versioning

When modifying documents in a SharePoint 2010 enterprise environment with major and minor versioning enabled, SharePoint keeps a version history for the document. The version history view though only shows changes to the title, date modified etc. How can I ensure that it shows ALL changes that have been made to the document?

Additionally this is actually an infopath document but I think the standard behaviour is the same for all office document types.

Thanks for any pointers

Answer (score 2):

The version history only monitors the meta-data changes, it is not able to identify or highlight content changes within the document; InfoPath, Word, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this:
http://www.mssharepointtips.com/tip.asp?id=1047&page=2